# jqGrid Wrapped JSON Data

Tags: json, jqgrid, master-detail

I have two jqgrids. One of them lists some groups and when I click any of that groups its sublist places at second grid. First grid works well however second grid doesn't. Second grid's data is like that:

```
{"devices":[{"type":"AAA","username":"username_0","password":"password_0","name":"devicename_0","description":"description","identity":null,"version":0,"systemId":0,"active":true}],"numberOfDevice":1,"name":"groupname_0","systemId":0,"active":true}
```

That part will be my second grid's source:

```
{"type":"AAA","username":"username_0","password":"password_0","name":"devicename_0","description":"description","identity":null,"version":0,"systemId":0,"active":true}
```

There may be more devices (they are under devicegroup) but there is one device at this example. How can I use that data at my jqgrid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use about the following `jsonReader`:

```
jsonReader: {
    root: 'devices',
    repeatitems: false,
    page: function () { return 1; },
    total: function () { return 1; },
    records: function (obj) { return obj.devices.length; }
}
```

See [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/kamaci1.htm).

Comment: can we define multiple root for a jsonReader?

Comment: @kamaci: I am not understand what you mean, but I suppose that the answer is "no, you can't". What format of the data you has exactly and what you want data you want to fill in the grid?